# How to keep linters from complaining about type hints that don't match on a technicality?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Considering the toy example:

```py
def get_dimensions(the_string: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    return tuple([int(_) for _ in the_string.split("x")])
```

I *know* that `the_string` will only ever contain on `x` (it's just the output of an `ffprobe` command), so I'm not concerned that this could return a tuple with more or less than 2 integers, but the reality is that linters like PyCharm are going to rightfully complain about the above as the type hint `tuple[int, int]` doesn't agree with the possible output of `tuple[int,...]`.

What's the right thing to do here?  I can adjust the last line there to use `maxsplit=1`, but that feels redundant, but I don't know of a way to indicate that `the_string` should only contain one `x` either.  Is there a "right" way to do this?  Should I just change the type hint?  Is setting `maxsplit=1` the preferred albeit pointlessly verbose style?  Is there some way to tell the linter not to worry about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `maxsplit`, you can split that line to:

```py
def get_dimensions(the_string: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    first, second = the_string.split("x")
    return int(first), int(second)
```

This could even be arguably more readable and explicit than the original and the main advantage over using `maxsplit` is that you will simply get an error whenever `the_string` will not match your assumption.

Comment: Ooh, I like this.  It avoids the list comprehension which is nice, and it's a little more explicit.

Comment: One could use `str.partition` to have a guarantee that the code will not crash if there are 2  x-es (if that is desired) - `first, _, second = the_string.partition("x")`

Comment: @matszwecja True (similar to using `maxsplit`). But my assumption is that if the input is assumed to always have only 1 `x`, it might be better to get an error if it doesn't. Using `maxsplit` or `partition` will silence that error (and might error-out later less clearly)